# unable to reduce react-native application's size

Tags: react-native

i made an app with expo but am not satisfied with it's size, i found this blog/tutoriel on how to reduce it using react-native init project , here is the link : https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640
the blog says to "Install all dependencies of the Expo project except Expo specific libraries." , but since i made the app with expo i used expo-av and expo-linear-gradient,it gave me this error 
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@unimodules/core` from

```
node_modules/expo-av/build/ExponentAV.js`: @unimodules/core could not be found within the project.
```

this error was fixed after i downloaded expo into the directory, it gave me a white screen but the build was succesfull.

when i removed the expo related libaries, it gave an error (ofcourse..).

NOTE : this isn't the first time that android studio emulator gives the white screen :( , so what am i doing wrong !!

here is the current package.json , i didn't change anything else in the project directory exept from adding the js files and the assets folder.

```
{
  "name": "fixemulatorBug",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-av": "5.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~5.0.1",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.61.3",
    "react-native-drawer": "2.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to install one packages.

try it;

`yarn add @unimodules/core`